# Geocoding in ARCGIS desktop with online basemaps

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geocoding, arcgis-online-basemaps

I would like to have your guidance about possible usage of online base maps in ArcGIS.

In ArcGIS Desktop there is a possibility to have access to some online maps (Satelite maps, Street Msps,...) provided by ESRI as backgroud info.

I would like to know if there is a possibility to do geocoding using this maps for some points.

Answer (score 2):

Yes - you can use the [ArcGIS Online Geocoding Service](https://geocode.arcgis.com/arcgis/index.html):

> If you are an ArcGIS for Desktop user, you can use this service for
>   finding addresses interactively or geocoding a table of addresses.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I wanted to get sure about it as there are some colleagues who arguing it is not possible to do it with basemaps.  I am going to try it.

Comment: It is not a basemap but it is ArcGIS Online.  It should also be accessible via the Find tool.

Comment: @user2355306 if you're living in Countries such as Iran, Syria, or other countries are restricted by embargo rules you have no any way except use VPN